# Delete file that has anti-delete security

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run code to delete a directory and all sub-directories. I'm just going to free up space with this so I don't need to actually clear the code off the drive. My problem occurs when the user has set up security on the file to prevent deletion. Is there a way to override this? Here's the code I'm using at the moment. (I'm new to VB so please be gentle.)

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(strProcRoot, DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)

Comment: I love these "can I override X" questions that seemingly just assume that things like windows file security is some afterthought that can be evaded with some lines of code, rather than an integral part of making windows a viable operating system for thousands of highly secure infrastructures..

Comment: Short answer no.  Long answer yes, but you probably don't want to try.

Comment: If the user has setup security to prevent you doing something, why are you trying to do it in the first place? If the user wanted that file deleted then they would not have taken measures to prevent you doing so. Stop trying to do things you shouldn't and then you won't have to try to solve such problems. Security is there for a reason. Stop being a bad person.

Comment: jmcilhinney - lol - not being a "bad person". The user wants me to archive this folder to an external drive. He doesn't want to have to go through and find all the files he had security on and change them. I just wanted to see if I could save him that effort.

Comment: It would seem that, by definition, if they can tell you what files they are so you can archive them on their behalf, then they must necessarily already know exactly what the files are, so it would seem trivial for the user to disable their protection.  The world already has enough malware problems without us posting public "how to bypass security" guides.